# Prevent rsync from trying to ask for a password

Tags: ssh, rsync

How do I prevent `rsync` from trying to ask for a password for the remote server login?

Note: I am not asking how to set up public key authenticated SSH. I *know* how to set up public key authenticated SSH. What I am asking is how to prevent `rsync` from trying to ask for a password if public key authentication *fails*, like what `scp`'s `-B` flag does. I am using `rsync` in a script here, so if it tries to ask for a password, my script will hang, waiting for input that will never come. I want the `rsync` command to instead fail, so my script can detect the failure and exit gracefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass options to the underlying `ssh` command used by `rsync`:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -oBatchMode=yes [other ssh options]' [rest of rsync command]
```

From the `rsync` manual:

> ```
> -e, --rsh=COMMAND           specify the remote shell to use
> ```

From the `ssh` manual:

> ```
> BatchMode
>
> If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled.
> This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no
> user is present to supply the password.  The argument must be
> “yes” or “no”.  The default is “no”.
> ```

This emulates the bahavior os `scp -B`.